# Equation number showing and don't know why

Tags: equations, numbering

I am trying to display this equation without any equation numbering using `eqnarray`. I have specified `\nonumber`, but the equation number still shows up. What do I need to do to fix this and why is occurring?

I can figure this out:

```
\begin{eqnarray}
\lefteqn{\bm{B}_s =  (\bm{B}_1 \oplus \bm{B}_2 \oplus \cdots \oplus   
\bm{B}_n)} \\ \nonumber
&& \qquad \qquad - \lambda_R \bm{e}'( \bm{p}_1 \otimes \bm{p}_2 \otimes 
\cdots \otimes \bm{p}_n), 
\end{eqnarray}
```

Comment: You are setting *two* equations and have only one `\nonumber`, so one of them (the first in this case) will be numbered.

Comment: There is a starred version to it `\begin{eqnarray*}` but there are several articles that show why you should not use eqnarray. I would suggest the equation or align environments.

Comment: Consider reading the following: [`eqnarray` vs `align`](http://goo.gl/3R7Ln)

Comment: Do you want the entire thing unnumbered? What does `\lefteqn` do? Instead of providing code snippets, provide a complete, minimal, working example (or MWE) that replicates your problem. It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @azetina - That seems to work. I've been using eqnarray for many years - I'll look into the other environments - Thanks

Comment: @Werner - The "lefteqn" breaks up 1 equation into 2 lines. The reason I did that was that the formula did not fit on 1 line in my paper.

Comment: @PMF: There is no visible way how `\lefteqn` breaks up its argument to split it across multiple rows from your code snippet...

Comment: `eqnaray`which is not recommended in any case is never intended to be used that way, the `=` is supposed be between the `&`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two lines in `eqnarray`, but just one `\nonumber`.

You *might* just use `eqnarray*`, but you should never use `eqnarray` to begin with. See [eqnarray vs align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align) and LaTeX guides which describe the much more powerful environments provided by `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\section{This is bad}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lefteqn{\bm{B}_s =  (\bm{B}_1 \oplus \bm{B}_2 \oplus \cdots \oplus   
\bm{B}_n)} \\
&& \qquad \qquad - \lambda_R \bm{e}'( \bm{p}_1 \otimes \bm{p}_2 \otimes 
\cdots \otimes \bm{p}_n), 
\end{eqnarray*}
\lipsum[3]

\newpage

\section{This is good}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{multline*}
\bm{B}_s = (\bm{B}_1 \oplus \bm{B}_2 \oplus \cdots \oplus \bm{B}_n)
\\
- \lambda_R \bm{e}'( \bm{p}_1 \otimes \bm{p}_2 \otimes \cdots \otimes \bm{p}_n), 
\end{multline*}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]